# Using a single preposition with multiple conjunctions

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, conjunctions

I found this in a passage:

> Recall that the prime subfield of a field is the smallest subfield, and is isomorphic to Fp for some p or **to Q**.

I noticed that every time the conjunction ( in above sentence, notice *or*) is used, the preposition ( in above sentence, notice *to* ) is also used to refer to the object.

Can it be written as:

Recall that the prime subfield of a field is the smallest subfield, and is isomorphic to Fp for some p **or  Q**

?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the word "or" or other conjunctions such as "and." Some nouns requires prepositions such as "to", "for" or "against." The word "isomorphic needs "to" because this is how it is used. It could have been another preposition. However, in any case after  "or " or "and"  at the end of the sentence the word isomorphic needs this preposition.

Answer (score 1):

*To* is used to tells us what else is part of relation (in the non-math sense): *F is isomorphic **to** K*.

The original parses like this

> Recall that the prime subfield of a field is the smallest subfield, and is isomorphic **(**to F<sub>p</sub> for some p**)** or **(**to Q**)**.

Your version can parse like this and could be confusing intitially

> ✗ Recall that the prime subfield of a field is the smallest subfield, and is isomorphic to F<sub>p</sub> for **(**some p or Q**)**.

In other words, the subfield is isomorphic to F<sub>p</sub> **or** F<sub>Q</sub>. You use your knowledge of the material to determine that this was not meant.

If it didn't have "for some p", then you could the omit *to* without confusion:

> <sup>OK</sup> Recall that the prime subfield of a field is the smallest subfield, and is isomorphic to F<sub>p</sub> or Q.

Of course, it's the author's decision on how precise they want to be with their language.

Comment: I've deleted my answer in favor of yours, as its better formatted and clearer. Also, who did you get the subscript notation in markdown?

Comment: `<sub>p</sub>` Basic features are in the [Markdown Help](https://ell.stackexchange.com/editing-help#html) page. However, they send you to Meta SE ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)) for a complete list of allowed HTML tags. There's also the [Formatting Sandbox](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2923/formatting-sandbox-please-test-stuff-here) on ELL Meta for a list of other tips.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase in question is **is isomorphic to {something}**.

It is isomorphic to {Fp, for some *p*} or [is isomorphic] to Q.

If we did not repeat the preposition **to** before "Q", it would be possible to take "Q" as an object of "for":  "for some p or Q", at least grammatically.

Normally context would disambiguate.   "Fp for some p or Q" can be eliminated as a possibility but not on *grammatical* grounds.